# I cannot use </script> in a question

Tags: support, markdown, design

Here I asked a question
[why </script> tag in js string is being validated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509818/why-script-tag-in-js-string-is-being-validated)

I used following string < / s c r i p t > without spaces between characters. and it is validated as actual close tag and not shown in my question. it works in comments , but it does not work in questions. I havent tried answers yet.
(this is working as expected </script>) (without \ character it is not working. here it is="")

Answer (score 5):

Use backticks: `

```
`</script>`
```

Answer (score 2):

In your question, you just needed to add backticks around the `</script>`.

Answer (score 2):

Indent 4 spaces, as defined in

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

which is linked from

- the small [?] to the upper right of every edit area
- the "full reference >> " link in the sidebar of any ask or edit page
- the /faq

Answer (score 1):

</script> using `&lt;/script>`

Comment: -1 Showing that **You** can do it without telling how it is done is no better than pointing a finger and saying *Look how clever* **I** *am* and laughing.

Comment: @Nifle: The fact that it can be done means you can [check the revisions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/61462/revisions) and [see the source](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/8411042f-7304-41fd-ab45-5519c2621c64/view-source). Now, laugh.

Comment: I didn't know that you could view revisions and I have been here over a year... And I still dont know how I would have been able to find the revisions if you had not written it in your comment. So a new user probably would have less of a clue. But in all honesty, had I known about revisions I would not downvoted but added a comment with the link to the source.

Comment: @Nifle: I edited it, now you can take back your down-vote

Comment: Downvote retracted.